# How to generate pdf file of text and image in linux?

Tags: linux, pdf, pdf-generation, email-attachments

I am generating a logfile on one of my servers.
Storing alot of data, then sending it to my mail once a month as a pdf file.

The prosess i am using is to 'cat' alot of commands to a text file, then convert it and send.

Is there any linux programs or some eazy way to do something simulare and add a image i have stored on the server in the pdf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that you just want to put the image at the end of the PDF.

You could first convert the image using `imagemagick` to a PDF doing this (will also work with different file types):

`convert image.jpg image.pdf`

Then, you can use a tool like `stapler` or `pdftk` to combine your generated text PDF and the `image.pdf` (you can add multiple images):

- `stapler cat text.pdf image.pdf  combined.pdf`
- `pdftk text.pdf image.pdf output combined.pdf`